# XSL include based on XSL:WHEN condition

Tags: xslt

I have a scenario here I have multiple xsl designed for different type of XML files. Now I have some application ID that is passed to my XSL library with  now I want to load different xsl based on this application ID values.

Like if my application ID is 1 
if application ID is 2

how can I do this???

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "passed to my XSL library"? Is the application ID inside the XML file, or is it coming from some other source?

Comment: _"different type of XML files"_ should mean different schema. Import all the stylesheet modules and use pattern matching regarding these schemas. `xsl:use-when` should be used for portability **between processors** not between schemas.

Comment: Yes my application ID is sent from the application.

Comment: @Alejandro - can't use code use-when as .net xslt.transform method doesnot support xslt 2.0

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT, `xsl:include` and `xsl:import` must be top-level elements, as said in [the specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-top-level) ([here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dt-top-level) for version 1.0).

That means that you can not condition the loading of another XSL file based on the XML you are applying the XSL to.